# number of strings which differ at atmost n positions?

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I have been given a string T comprised of only 's','t','u','v' as characters . I want to find numbers of strings with length |T| which differs at atmost n position from T. Also each such string must not have same character at three different locations which are separated by same distance . My approach is using dynamic programming method such that dp[i][j][k] denotes number of such strings of length i , differing at j position while ending at kth character , where k=s,t,u,v .

if(k is same at ith character of T)

dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-1][j][0]+dp[i-1][j][1]+dp[i-1][j][2]-(strings which are extra due to k added at ith location and violates condition of same separated distance )

but i know this is wrong ?

eg for this is suppose T ='sstt' and we have to find strings which differ at most 2 locations then strings which do not have same character at three different location separated by same distance are 'tstt', 'ssts' and etc

Comment: What does "three different locations which are separated by same distance" mean?

Comment: @j_random_hacker eg 'ttt' , 'ststst' are invalid  . In first 't' are at distance one from each other , while in second ststst they are at distance two from each other at three different locations

Comment: This looks pretty hard to me -- I can't even figure out how to calculate the total number of strings obeying this constraint, let alone the number that also satisfy the Hamming distance constraint!

Comment: Of course, there's always generate-and-test, but that's almost never the fastest way.  But what I also want to say is: This is definitely a question from a programming competition, so please give us a link to it so that we can verify that it has finished (so that we wouldn't be helping you unfairly).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be really interesting. Perhaps you could enumerate the number of two-pairs and then proceed with that?